# Name for this simple inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functional-analysis

Let $x,y$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. From
$$\Vert x+y\Vert^2\geq 0$$ it follows that
$$2x\cdot y\geq -\Vert x\Vert^2-\Vert y\Vert^2$$
Has this inequality a name?

Comment: I don't know a name for the inequality, but it can be viewed as a poor cousin of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$x\cdot y \geq -||x||\cdot||y||$$ since it produces a weaker bound via the following version of the arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean inequality applied to the two real numbers $||x||^2$ and $||y||^2$, _viz._ $$x\cdot y \geq -||x||\cdot||y|| = -\sqrt{||x||^2||y||^2} \geq -\frac{||x||^2+||y||^2}{2}.$$

Comment: Maybe it's too obvious and so it has not a name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality is trivially equivalent to the inequality $$x\cdot y\le\frac{\lVert x\rVert^2}{2}+\frac{\lVert y\rVert^2}{2}$$ which can be thought of as a vector version of [Young's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality). You can also replace $x$ by $x/\sqrt\varepsilon$ and $y$ by $\sqrt\varepsilon y$ to get the vector version of the Peter–Paul inequality
$$x\cdot y\le\frac{\lVert x\rVert^2}{2\varepsilon}+\frac{\varepsilon\lVert y\rVert^2}{2}$$ which is frequently quite useful in PDE theory.